# display braintree errors on fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, haml, braintree

hi i am trying to get my braintree account to display errors when creating a transaction but it doesn't appear to be working

```
- flash.each do |key, value|
              %div{:class => "alert alert-#{key}"}= value


def update
    result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
        :amount => params[:amount_to_add].to_f,
        # :order_id => "order id",
        :customer_id => customer.customer_cim_id,
        :tax_amount => (params[:amount_to_add].to_f / 11).round(2),
        :options => {
            :submit_for_settlement => true
        }

    )
    if result.success?
      logger.info "Added to #{params[:amount_to_add].to_f} to #{customer.first_name} #{customer.last_name} (#{customer.customer_cim_id})"
      customer.store_credit.add_credit(params[:amount_to_add].to_f)
      redirect_to myaccount_store_credit_path
      # , :notice => "Successfully updated store credit."
    else
      result.errors.each do |error|
        puts error.message
        customer.errors.add(:base, error.message)
        render :show, :notice => error.message
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: i get the response in my terminal but i am trying to work out how to present these errors back to the view

Comment: this isnt really answering my question, i just want to return the error that braintree is giving me to the presentation layer

Comment: not sure if you are following what i actually need, as to why the errors aren't being served to the presentation layer like they should

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason you're probably unable to see the errors is because of the `:notice` option on your `render` method, which is redundant because `render` doesn't seem to be using the `:notice` option, only `redirect_to`. You may just add the errors to your to your `flash`, but note that in your view you have to loop through the errors within the flash to render it.

Another way I would think you do this though is add the payment method to your User model

```
class User|Customer
   ...

   def process_braintree_payment(amount)
     result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
        :amount => amount.to_f,
        # :order_id => "order id",
        :customer_id => customer_cim_id,
        :tax_amount => (amount.to_f / 11).round(2),
        :options => {
            :submit_for_settlement => true
        }
    )
    add_braintree_errors(result.error) unless result.success?
   end

   def add_braintree_errors(error_object)
     error_object.each do |error|
       errors.add(:braintree, error.message)
     end
   end
end

class XController
  def update
    @customer.process_braintree_payment(params[:amount_to_add])
    if @customer.errors.empty?
      logger.info "Added to #{params[:amount_to_add].to_f} to #{@customer.first_name} #{@customer.last_name} (#{@customer.customer_cim_id})"
      @customer.store_credit.add_credit(params[:amount_to_add].to_f)
      redirect_to myaccount_store_credit_path
      # , :notice => "Successfully updated store credit."
    else
      render :show
    end
  end
end
```

In your view, you have access to the @customer variable or better you could store the error object in the `ActionController#flash`, note however, using the same keys for your flash messages, would overwrite the previous value.

Comment: think this is on the right track, though the process_braintree_payment gives me undefined method

Comment: Where do you get this error? My assumption was that you had the `@customer` variable set, otherwise you'd be trying to call the method on a nil object

Comment: this is all done in my store credit controller/model with a custom method for customer `def customer
    @customer ||= User.includes(:store_credit).find(current_user.id)
  end`